# Ignoring the index of values when creating a pivot table

Tags: python, pandas

Consider the dataframe

```
  group  score
0     A    1.0
1     B    1.2
2     A    2.4
3     C    1.7
4     D    3.5
5     C    4.9
```

I want

```
         A    B    C     D
0      1.0  1.2  1.7   3.5
1      2.4  NaN  4.9   NaN
```

I have tried

```
df.pivot(columns='group', values='score')
```

producing

```
group    A    B    C    D
0      1.0  NaN  NaN  NaN
1      NaN  1.2  NaN  NaN
2      2.4  NaN  NaN  NaN
3      NaN  NaN  1.7  NaN
4      NaN  NaN  NaN  3.5
5      NaN  NaN  4.9  NaN
```

I want to "reduce" the introduced NaN values as can be seen in the desired output.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Create a new column using [`groupby.cumcount`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.cumcount.html) and use that as your index when pivoting:

```
(df.assign(idx=df.groupby('group').cumcount())
 .pivot(index='idx', columns='group', values='score'))
```

[out]

```
group    A    B    C    D
idx                      
0      1.0  1.2  1.7  3.5
1      2.4  NaN  4.9  NaN
```

---

**Detail**

Without pivoting, adding the `cumcount` looks like this:

```
df.assign(idx=df.groupby('group').cumcount())

  group  score  idx
0     A    1.0    0
1     B    1.2    0
2     A    2.4    1
3     C    1.7    0
4     D    3.5    0
5     C    4.9    1
```

Comment: Ha, that's clever!

Answer (score 1):

I just found a solution. I don't know if it is the most elegant.

```
>>> df.pivot(columns='group', values='score').apply(lambda s: s.dropna().reset_index(drop=True))
group    A    B    C    D
0      1.0  1.2  1.7  3.5
1      2.4  NaN  4.9  NaN
```